# Tomcat v8 suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I am using Eclipse java ee Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) and apache-tomcat-8.0.30. I was trying to start a project that should have worked and keep on getting 404s, so i tried to run older working projects to see if it was an eclipse problem, suddenly i got that an eclipse problem *Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.*

I have already tried solutions I found. But in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start) link that I have no file *.snap* in that directory. I've also tried [this](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/tomcat-eclipse-error-starting-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-has-encountered-a-problem/), but it didn't work.

Comment: You may add the solution that worked for you as answer below as that may help some one in future.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found of the problem was a severe log *SEVERE: A child container failed during start*. So I googled it and found out I had to remove a class [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373077/tomcat-7-severe-a-child-container-failed-during-start), to solve this i removed the last project i was working with, then tomcat started working properly again