# Error tomcat7-maven: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

I got this error when I run my project:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project gdp-war: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component 
[StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component 
[StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed.
```

My configuration:

```
Java version: 1.7.0-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Any Ideas? Thanks alot for your help.

Here is my pom

```
    [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>gdp-base</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.rcl.gdp</groupId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>gdp-war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WAR - Web Application Project for GDP</name>

<properties>
    <main.basedir>${basedir}/..</main.basedir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <webapp.context>/cruiseplanner</webapp.context>
    <webapp.servlet.port>8080</webapp.servlet.port>
    <webapp.stop.port>9999</webapp.stop.port>
    <cargo.container.id>tomcat7x</cargo.container.id>
    <cargo.download.url>http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.55/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.55.zip</cargo.download.url>
    <maven-cargo.version>1.4.3</maven-cargo.version>
    <orika.version>1.4.3</orika.version>]
```

And the command that i used was:
[mvn -DskipTests tomcat7:run  -DdisableCache=true -P live]

Comment: Could you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373077/tomcat-7-severe-a-child-container-failed-during-start ?

Comment: What command did you use? What configuration?

Comment: It would be nice to see your pom.xml and which command you tried to execute.