# Netbeans Maven Spring boot error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a error like this.I workin on netbeans maven spring boot.

```
   Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Osman/Documents/sdn-twitter-boot-master/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-rest/3.1.0.M1/spring-data-neo4j-rest-3.1.0.M1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.7.4/aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.0.1/neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/3.1.0.M1/spring-data-neo4j-3.1.0.M1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.4/aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.8.0.M1/spring-data-commons-1.8.0.M1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-dsl-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb/2.0.1/neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.7/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.7/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.7/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.9/jersey-client-1.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j/2.0.1/neo4j-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index/2.0.1/neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.6.2/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/2.0.1/neo4j-graph-algo-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-udc/2.0.1/neo4j-udc-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-matching/2.0.1/neo4j-graph-matching-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-jmx/2.0.1/neo4j-jmx-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-commons/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-commons-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/1.1.6/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.6/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.3.1/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.3/scala-library-2.10.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.1.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.52/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.52/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.52.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.52/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.52.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.9.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-core/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/atteo/evo-inflector/1.0.1/evo-inflector-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/social/spring-social-twitter/1.0.5.RELEASE/spring-social-twitter-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/social/spring-social-core/1.0.3.RELEASE/spring-social-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-test-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/de/codecentric/spring-boot-admin-server/1.0.5/spring-boot-admin-server-1.0.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/de/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-admin-client/1.0.5/spring-boot-starter-admin-client-1.0.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/jolokia/jolokia-core/1.2.0/jolokia-core-1.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.3/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.3/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bootstrap/2Exception in thread "main" .3.2/bootstrap-2.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/1.11.0/jquery-1.11.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/angularjs/1.2.12/angularjs-1.2.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/angular-ui-router/0.2.10-1/angular-ui-router-0.2.10-1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/angularjs-nvd3-directives/0.0.7-1/angularjs-nvd3-directives-0.0.7-1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/d3js/3.4.11/d3js-3.4.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/webjars/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nvd3-1.1.15-beta.jar, file:/C:/Users/Osman/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.0/objenesis-1.0.jar]
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at org.neo4j.twitter_graph.TwitterApplication.main(TwitterApplication.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 18 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 14.924s
Finished at: Sun May 14 14:48:12 MSK 2017
Final Memory: 10M/158M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default-cli) on project sdn-twitter-graph: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Have you checked your server log? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512588/tomcat-lifecycleexception-when-deploying Maybe in the "18 more" it's the real cause on initializing some of your project specific beans.

Answer (score 0):

You might start working on these troubleshooting steps to identify/resolve the issue:

- Looked for multiple jars/versions
- Tomcat & Java compatibility
- Clean /Restart/Reimport the project

If it still not resolved then you might look for specific jars like `Servlet3`. `Spring Boot`depends on `Servlet 3` or higher to work, check for these issues.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373077/tomcat-7-severe-a-child-container-failed-during-start) for more details!