# Java EE, Tomcat and SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

When I add the below code to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And hit "Run on Server", I get the following error:

I don't know whats is going on, I create another project and the error continues.
I'm using eclipse, and tomcat 8.0, java 1.8.

**Starting Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem.
 Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**

And in the console:

```
*SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/smvctt]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
```

Comment: Dependency should not impact on startup of your server. Did you try to start server stand alone????

Comment: Start server and deploy the generated war file from tomcat administration gui. I believe this should be a configuration issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373115/6756805 you can refer this

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean Tomcat work directory, rebuild (since you have added new dependencies ) and redeploy the project and start the server.

Comment: How I do that, please? @Kumar

Comment: Right click of Tomcat server in Eclipse and click on "Clean Tomcat Work Directory"